# Difference between Heatmap in QGIS and Kernel Density in SAGA

Tags: qgis, saga, heat-map, kernel-density

I'm trying to migrate my workflow from QGIS to SAGA so that I can automate it from the command line or a standalone Python script. Part of the workflow is running a KDE (or rather, a series of KDEs). When I run the Heatmap tool in QGIS, I get this output, which looks very much like what I expect to see.

[image: Heatmap of data processed in QGIS]

When I take the same data and perform the Kernel density estimation in SAGA (actually in SAGA 8.3.0, not using QGIS), I get this output:

[image: Kernel density estimation processed in SAGA]

Which is not at all what I expect to see. Note that the shading is scaled based on standard deviations. If this were a linear scale, the only dot visible would be the one at the bottom of the map.

Of particular note, the range of the QGIS output is 0 to 1428. The range of the SAGA output is -1236 to 0.21.

Here are the parameters for the Heatmap in QGIS:

[image]

And in SAGA:
[image: SAGA KDE parameters]

Why am I getting such wildly different outputs from the same dataset?